# SML higher order function type?

Tags: list, functional-programming, reverse, sml, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to implement a function

```
 ziprev : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b)list
 - ziprev [1,2,3,4] [10,20,30,40];
 val it = [(1,40),(2,30),(3,20),(4,10)] : (int * int) list
```

Using zipWith and the List.rev from the library.

I'm having trouble as to what the function is. Attempt:

```
fun ziprev xs ys = List.zipWith(List.rev(fn(a,b) => (a,b)::[]),xs,ys);
```

Operator : 'Z list   Operand: 'Y * 'X -> ('Y * 'X) list

Comment: Did you get your `zip` implementation using `zipWith` working? The next step from there should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `List.zipWith` in the SML basis library, so I don't know where you have that one from; and List.rev doesn't take a function as argument, it takes a list as argument

```
- rev;
val it = fn : 'a list -> 'a list
```

I guess what you are trying to accomplish is something of the lines of `ListPair.zip` instead

```
- fun ziprev xs ys = ListPair.zip(xs, rev ys);
val ziprev = fn : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list

- ziprev [1,2,3,4] [10,20,30,40];
val it = [(1,40),(2,30),(3,20),(4,10)] : (int * int) list
```

Comment: fun zipWith f (x::xs) (y::ys) = (f x y) :: (zipWith f xs ys)
  | zipWith _    _       _    = []; Thanks anyways